# Catel Exception: Failed to get string for resource name 'PleaseWait'

Tags: c#, mvvm, catel

Using Catel 4.4.0.

I'm doing some clean-up work on my applications and looked through the error logs.  I see several exceptions like the one listed below every time my app starts.  My app doesn't appear to be affected (doesn't crash or display a popup), but I would like to eliminate exceptions such as these. Is there a fix for this? Or maybe, fixed in a newer Catel version? I'm probably not understanding the instructions on the first line of the exception.  Please let me know if you need more information.  Thanks!

```
01/13/2017 21:25:57.4817 [LogAlways][128]: Catel: Failed to get string for resource name 'PleaseWait' from resource file 'Catel.Services.Models.LanguageResourceSource' | [MissingManifestResourceException] System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Catel.Properties.Exceptions.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Catel.Core" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at Catel.Services.LanguageService.GetString(ILanguageSource languageSource, String resourceName, CultureInfo cultureInfo) in C:\CI_WS\Ws\86058\Source\Catel\src\Catel.Core\Catel.Core.Shared\Services\LanguageService.xaml.cs:line 91
   at Catel.Services.LanguageService.GetStringInternal(String resourceName, CultureInfo cultureInfo) in C:\CI_WS\Ws\86058\Source\Catel\src\Catel.Core\Catel.Core.Shared\Services\LanguageService.cs:line 177
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are first-chance exceptions (which can be ignored) when Catel is looking up the required resources in the different resource dictionaries. Catel goes through all of the registered resource files one by one and tries to resolve the right resource.

The results of these calls are cached internally so it doesn't have to go through all of the resource files a second time.

Comment: Is there an easy way to keep Catel from logging this particular exception?  I get 2 exceptions logged each time I start any of my applications.  Thanks!

Comment: No, but you can:

1. Implement a custom LanguageService and don't log these exceptions
2. Ignore these calls in your log listener

Comment: Thanks!  I'll see what I can do in the log listener.